# Get line number for Missing Character

Tags: xetex, unicode, missing

I do conversion of many documents from XML (Unicode) to XeLaTeX.
I stumbled upon x≠5, in one document, for which my Software failed to translate the character to `\neq` (due to Unicode composite character).

I do parse the Logfile for 'Missing Character' and afterwards look at each case individually.
To find the error in the tex-file fast, I want to output the line number too.
If the character itself is hidden in some makro, I want to get the call line number, not the definition.

Is there any way to achieve this?
Simple grep for `̸` would find line 2 in this example, but I need line 4:

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\def\someChar{≠} %def may be in another file, so grep is not sufficient
\begin{document}
x \someChar 5
\end{document}
```

In the real world, I tried to use the line numbers from surrounding `Overfull \hbox` warnings, but this is error prone.
In the following log I assumed the character to be beetween line 982 and 993, but it actually was in line 886. (one section earlier)

```
Overfull \hbox (325.02254pt too wide) detected at line 982
\EU2/Cambria.ttf(0)/bx/n/10.54 Sta-ti-sche axiale Trag-zahl für ein-sei-tig un
d zwei-sei-tig wir-kende Lager
 []    

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active
\EU2/Cambria.ttf(0)/bx/n/10.54 14
 []

[14
Missing character: There is no ̸ (U+0338) in font [Cambria]:mode=node;script=la
tn;language=DFLT;+tlig;!
]
Overfull \hbox (273.26788pt too wide) detected at line 993
```

I expect similar errors to happen, so it would be really helpful to find the relevant spots fast (so I can spend my time fixing them).

If this is not possible, are there any other hints I could use to at least narrow the region to search?

Comment: Why don't you want to get the line with the definition? If you want to correct it this is the place where you should do it.

Comment: Beside this: The `Missing character:` message is issued when the page is shipped out, so you can only know the page number.

Comment: the log shows you that it is on page 14 `[14 ....` That is as precise as you can easily get from xetex.

Comment: I would ignore the location information, just collect up the full list of missing characters then do a global replace over the document removing those characters (eg replacing the combining negation usage here by the not equals character U+2260

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I want to know where the character is missing.
If I change anything, I need to know where to look for improvements.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh that's the page number... I need to further understand the log, clearly. :)
This is what I was looking for.

Comment: the fact that the warning is between `[14` and `]` tells you that, as @UlrikeFischer says above the problem is detected not while the source is being read but while the page is being shipped out as `[14` is the start of the shipout (when `\count0=14`) and `]` is the end.

Comment: This is what I use to parse only pages and Missing glyphs from Logfile, assuming that `[14` can only be the page number:

`sed -n -e "/^\[/{s/^\[\([0-9]*\).*/on page \1:<br\/>/;h};/^Missing/{s/\(.*\)/\1<br\/>/;x;p;s/.*//;x;p}" out.log > glyphs.log`